Implementing iterator for map implementation in C++
[Fixed] Adding typename before RBT
I implemented a RedBlackTree from scratch and now I want to implement an ordered map from scratch using that RBT.
I have a class RBT and inside of it a struct called TreeNode.
I have a separate class Map and inside of it a class called Iterator.
The problem is that when I try to declare a TreeNode pointer inside my Iterator it won't recognize it
class Iterator
{
    RBT<KeyType, ValueType, Compare>::TreeNode* node;
    Map& map;
public:
    Iterator(RBT<KeyType, ValueType, Compare>::TreeNode* nodePointer, Map& mapReference)
        : node(nodePointer), map(mapReference) {}
...
}

I tried to do forward declarations,to make the class Map and class Iterator friends of the class RBT but it still won't work.

it won't recognize it -- What is the exact error message?  Also, please post a [mcve].

You need to add typename before RBT.

Adding typename before RBT fixed the problem.Thank you!
